# Need of transformer function

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am linking to a webservice all works fine. Below is my codes.

```
private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = \n");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);     
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }
```

I am not too sure of the transformerfactory. What I need to do now is to traverse through the results and look for below tag.

`<Table diffgr:id="Table1" >` and there after there will be few tags in it for e.g.

```
<rID>1212</rID>
<sNo>15677</sNo>
```

So what is the best way as some require to covert it into string is that necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform to document (unchecked):

```
      TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
      Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();  
      DOMResult result = new DOMResult();  
      transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);  
      Document doc = (Document) result.getNode();
```

Find in document:

```
        String tag = "Table";
        String attr = "diffgr:id";
        String attrValue = "Table1";
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");
        Element tableNode = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            tableNode = ((Element) list.item(i));
            String currentAttrValue = tableNode.getAttribute(attr);
            if (attrValue.equals(currentAttrValue)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        String childTag1 = "rID";
        String childTag2 = "sNo";
        Node child1 = (Node) tableNode.getElementsByTagName(childTag1).item(0);
        Node child2 = (Node) tableNode.getElementsByTagName(childTag2).item(0);
        String rIDValue = child1.getTextContent();
        String sNoValue = child1.getTextContent();
```

Comment: I tried printing nothing but I added this line for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
         System.out.println("Table is :"+i); and I notice it gets so what else can I do ? OR how to print all the elements found under tag Table ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to print every element but I don't think that's you're traget. I've edited my code to show you how you can access subnodes values. Hope it will help.

Comment: For the benefits of the rest I manage to do and in the loop I did this Element eElement = (Element) e.getChildNodes();
          
String rID= eElement.getElementsByTagName("rID").item(0).getTextContent();
          System.out.println("\nrID:" + rID);

Answer (score 0):

You code `Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();` is creating an "identity transformer" which copies the input unchanged, so it's not really doing anything useful. What you want here is a real (XSLT) transformer which actually extracts the information you need: something like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//Table[@diffgr:id='Table1']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which you can compile using transformerFactory.newTemplates().

Comment: so do I need to use this part of the codes TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
      Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();  ? I am kind of new and lost.

Comment: There are plenty of good tutorials on the JAXP transformation API, I'm not going to try and write another one in a comment field.